# Transformer changing voltages at input

Tags: transformer, ac, input

I have a confusion regarding the input voltage of the transformer. Is it necessary that the input voltage of the transformer should change its direction. If I give an input voltage, a sine wave but no negative voltage, or the output of a full wave rectifier. In that case the voltage levels are also changing but the direction does not...so will I get the desired result?

Comment: If I follow you, then no. Think about volt-seconds (Webers) as magnetic charge. Unlike a capacitor's charge, time is part of what makes up magnetic charge. If there is a DC bias, even if it is a changing DC, then the Webers will accumulate towards infinity. And that's a very bad thing if you are depending on a core other than vacuum. Imagine you have a sine wave but offset by just enough to ensure it is always positive (or always negative) one lead to the other lead. Then the Webers will accumulate in one direction without limit as time proceeds. Not so good and very high currents.

Comment: Using capacitors as an analogy, imagine having a varying current source but where the current source is always in one direction only. Eventually, charge would have to build up on the capacitor with the result of extremely high voltages present across the capacitor. Also not good. A capacitor also, at some point, must have both discharge and charge taking place. It can be biased (like the input capacitor for an amplifier stage) with some DC charge. But around that, it must vary in such a way that the charge is in equilibrium over time.

Comment: I should add that it is possible for discontinuous mode operation to use only one-sided (positive-only or negative-only) voltages. So long as it is discontinuous and that the **off** period is long enough for the Webers to discharge to zero before the next cycle. In continuous mode operation, there will be an equilibrium of accumulated Webers around which the cycle period operates. But the accumulation around that operating point must be balanced by `decumulation` that matches up with the accumulation so that the steady state value remains stable.

Comment: The reason that magnetic charge is time-dependent has to do with the fact that there are no magnetic monopoles. Or put another way, the classical concepts of electric and magnetic fields have been replaced by a relativistic understanding. The effect of charges moving are only *felt* at the speed of light. The classical interpretation assumes an instantaneous electric field effect. Since it actually **isn't** instantaneous, this means it takes ***time*** for the effect. Magnetism is what happens when you assume instant electric fields and reality impinges on that false assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *In that case the voltage levels are also changing but the direction is
> not...so will I get the desired result?*

No, you won't get the desired result. The flux in the core will ramp up until the core saturates and then you are in trouble. The flux in the core ideally needs to have an average value of zero and any DC offset will ruin this.

Think about a simple inductor and relate this to the primary of the transformer. You can ignore the secondary. If you apply any DC voltage level to an ideal inductor, the current will ramp up until you cannot supply any more current.

> *Is it necessary that the input voltage of the transformer should
> change its direction.*

It's absolutely necessary. This is why low frequency transformers for household AC supplies are so big compared to the miniscule transformers you get inside switching converters (they operate at circa 100 kHz).

The higher frequency means you can use many fewer turns and have a smaller core to transmit the equivalent power to the secondary.